# BIND9 failing to start 

Tags: linux, bind

(resolved: AppArmor was the reason of that failure. I just run: aa-logprof and restarted bind)

I added second interface to my server

and after I restarted my server I have found out that BIND is not starting.

If I try: sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
I'm. getting

```
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9
    rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
                                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9
                                                               [fail]
```

contents from /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug 12 15:50:36 server1 named[1127]: configuring TKEY: failure
Aug 12 15:50:36 server1 named[1127]: loading configuration: failure
Aug 12 15:50:36 server1 named[1127]: exiting (due to fatal error)
Aug 12 15:50:36 server1 kernel: [   38.746404] type=1400 audit(1313142636.718:15): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_lock" parent=1126 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/usr/local/samba/private/dns.keytab" pid=1128 comm="named" requested_mask="k" denied_mask="k" fsuid=103 ouid=103
```

However I think the problem is not coming from the second interface as I removed it and rebooted. Having the same issue.

Comment: You should write a description of your solution and how you arrived at it in an answer, which you should then accept. This way people having the same issue can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppArmor was the reason of that failure. He just ran: aa-logprof and restarted bind.

<sub>(Blatently stolen from the Question, but he didn't post it as an answer)</sub>

Comment: I just didn't have enough permissions to post an answer for my own question for 8 hours after question was published

Answer (score 11):

Run this:

```
named -g
```

It will start the bind9 server in foreground and print all the errors it encounters to stderr so you can figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: thank you, I have updated the question and added messages from /var/log/syslog
If I run named -g I am getting the same except the last line

Comment: Are you running your system with selinux policy set to 'enforcing' by any chance?

Comment: O G, I am running Ubuntu Server I think there is no selinux. Thereis an apparmor. But I configured apparmor..and it worked fine earlier. No idea why now. The only change I made is added new interface. But I removed it..and problem is still here.

Comment: See permissions in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named and have the zone files in that location (/var/cache/bind I think).

Comment: var cache bind already set look:

  /var/cache/bind/** rw,
  /var/cache/bind/ rw,

Comment: Try putting it into 'complain' mode with apparmor and see exactly what is the cause (aa-complain /usr/sbin/named # as root or via sudo)

Comment: I set to complain mode, then I'm running sudo named. I think the problem is coming from: 12-Aug-2011 16:23:02.474 configuring TKEY: failure
12-Aug-2011 16:23:02.474 loading configuration: failure
12-Aug-2011 16:23:02.474 exiting (due to fatal error)

do you know what is tkey failure

Comment: see this link and if it helps: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=472373

Comment: AppArmor was the reason of that failure.

I just run: aa-logprof and restarted bind

Thanks!